# Azure AD two Apps SSO

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, single-page-application

Stackoverflow I need your help.

Introduction:
We have two applications that are available through separate domains. These two applications are currently provisioned using Azure AD and PKCE login.
Azure AD manages the clients.

My question now: is it possible to configure Azure AD to allow SSO through these two applications.
Customer logs into application A and switches to B and is logged in there immediately, so without entering PW again.
Somehow I haven't found a tutorial or something similar that looks at this case, maybe I'm searching for the wrong keywords.

Thanks a lot

Application A has A customers -> a.de -> Angular SPA
Application B has A and B customers -> b.de -> Angular SPA

Yeah, hmm, what I tried. I was looking for tutorials or something like that.
I Hope this is possible with Azure AD

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.
However, this is not yet finally tested, so to enjoy with caution.

Hints:

The scopes must be enabled in the azure.portal for the applications otherwise it gets stuck in a kind of login loop.

portal.app-reg(not Enterprise APP).Api Permission

In the initial component in ngInit:

```
 const activeAccount = this.authService.instance.getActiveAccount();
 const activeAccountEmail = activeAccount?.username;

 //loginhin for ssoSilent
 const silentRequest: SsoSilentRequest = {
     scopes: ['User.Read'], //a scope (aka "permission") refers to any aspect of a resource that an Access Token grants rights.
     loginHint: activeAccountEmail
 };

 //silentsso on inital pageload/reload
 this.authService.ssoSilent(silentRequest)
     .subscribe({
         next: (result: AuthenticationResult) => {
             console.log('SsoSilent succeeded!');
         },
         error: (error) => {
             console.error("ERROR: "+error);
             this.authService.loginRedirect();
         }
     });
```